# GWT - click event on day in DatePicker

Tags: gwt, click, datepicker

In GWT I want to handle the click event, but only when user clicks on a day.
There's a valueChangeHandler but it fires when value change, so when I click two times at the same day it will fire once.

Other option is to use addHandler or addDomHandler in which I can add ClickHandler, but it fires always, no matter if I click a day or if I pass to other month.

Both options for me are not functional.
Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the addvalueChangeHandler then after that set the value to something else. It's a hack but it works for me.

```java
calendarWidget.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
  @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
      calendarWidget.setValue(new Date(0));
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you should describe more details . I don't know exactly what you really want to do.
Here my advices.

(1). Use [Cookies](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html) to save infomation of current used user and set expire day to 1day.

(2). Don't use addNewHandler. You should use global variable of one handler instance and initialize it to NULL . At first tought to this , you would be initialized it. That may creat only one time and you can check is it NULL . eg:

```
private CloseHandler handler;
.......
        if (handler == null) {
        handler = new CloseHandler<PopupPanel>() {
            public void onClose(final CloseEvent<PopupPanel> event) {
                ........
            }
        };
    }
```

(3). You can also use simple handler as you with and if fired event to it , save in a **Map** with current time and unique value (eg:sequence of login user.etc). When after hit it again , you retrive and match the times of both current and previous.

Be useful for you..

Comment: Sorry.. I'm talking about widget called DatePicker (it's something like calendar) and I want to handle the event when user clicks on it, but only when he click on a day. 

For example I have this widget. User clicks on a day, than I show him some popup. When he clicks on widget, but not on a day.. for example when he pass to next month I don't show popup.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry. Now I know you mean com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox. You have two options.(1). click or focus on DateBox widget (2). click on day that from popup of DateBox wiget. Am I right ?

Comment: [GWT: Extend The DatePicker/CalendarView](http://ctasada.blogspot.com/2010/08/gwt-extend-datepickercalendarview.html). That may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add handler on your DateBox.getDatePicker() and your DateBox.getTextBox().
You can add another handlers as like this...

```
     dateBox.addHandler(new ClickHandler() {

     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
     Window.alert("click"); 
     }
     }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Comment: The above solution doesn't work. Click event for selection of date doesn't get fired.